# perl parent branch of fork behaving anomalously

Tags: perl, fork

I have the following code in the parent branch of a fork.  That is, in the side of the branch for which $pid = fork has a $pid that is non-zero.  My problem is that both of the print statements give the same value for $num_run, namely zero.  Both prints are executed, so the inside of the if clause is reached.  Why is $num_run not being incremented??  I do realize this seems impossible.  Any help will be hugely appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    print BATCHLOG "$$: 1 parent num_run is $num_run\n";
    if ($active_runs < $CORES) {
       push @active_pids, $pid;
       $num_rum = $num_run + 1;
       print BATCHLOG "$$: 2 parent num_run is $num_run\n";
       next;
    }
```

Comment: Given the thousands of times we have given the advice to *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, it is astonishing that there are still so many people whom the news hasn't yet reached. In any case, the increment operators `++` are available in most languages (except Lua), and the statememt `$num_run = $num_run + 1` is more safely and clearly written as `++$num_run`.

Comment: @Borodin Python doesn't have `++` or `--` either fyi

Comment: @stevieb: That's true, but you can write `num_run += 1` which is every bit as good. In Lua, you are forced to say `num_run = num_run + 1` which increases the chance of making the OP's mistake.

Comment: @Borodin yeah, I knew about the `x += 1` in Python, but I didn't realize that in Lua it was so different. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

`$num_rum` is not `$num_run`

Comment: How did you even spot that?  I had to re-read it three times _after_ seeing your answer :)

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid like that -- I suppose I should have done a search for num_run...  Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer that's going to end up in the review queue for a while. :-)